# Scheduling task two times per business day at fixed time with check for "green light"

Tags: java, timer, cron, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

I am working on automating a task in java that is being run manually 2 times per business day, at fixed times.
This task has to check in database if it can run (if some other task is running, it cannot start). I've exported the task into a jar file and created a new eclipse workspace in which the tasks would run, but i could not find a good solution to this problem, mostly because of this task running 2 times per day, with fixed times (7am, 1pm) and it has to check in database for the "green light".

I know that there are solutions as **Timer, ScheduledExecutorService** and external scheduling service **Quartz**. I have looked into these solutions, but i dont think they really fit my problem.

I dont wanna end up reinveting the wheel with creating a timer from scratch so I was wondering if somebody has had experience with scheduling tasks the same way i need.

I imagine the solution would look like this:

```
Task task7am = new Task();
Task task1pm = new Task();

// 1st parameter : which days of week it should run
// 2nd parameter : which hour of day it should run
task7am.schedule("1 2 3 4 5", 7); 
task1pm.schedule("1 2 3 4 5", 13); 

SomeTaskScheduleService service = new SomeTaskScheduleService();

service.add(task7am);
service.add(task1pm);

service.start();
```

The Task class:

```
class Task extends TaskServiceXXX{
    @Override
    public void run () {
       //check if it can run
       while(!DbUtil.canRunTask()){
           sleep();
       }
       doTheTask();
    }

    private void sleep(){
       Thread.sleep(1000*60*5); //wait 5 minutes
    }
   
    private void doTheTask(){
       //the task, which needs to be done
    }

}
```

If you could help, even by pointing to documentation i would be really grateful. Thank you

Comment: Consider using Spring. It provides the annotation @Scheduled where you can define the cron-like parameters. In your case something like @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 7,13 * * MON-FRI").
Checking if the job can run and waiting until it can need to be implemented however. Your Task class is a good start.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I haven't had experience with Spring yet because when building customer enterprise applications I've only used J2EE (enterprise beans). Didn't really know that I can use Spring for something other than microservices. I will look into it and try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of researching, I found Quartz to be the most useful in my situation (spring was a bit overkill). The biggest downside to Quartz tho, is that this library is not mantained anymore (so no support).